# How to return an enum ID instead of the enum text in WebAPI

Tags: enums, asp.net-web-api

I am using the WebAPI with .NET 4.5. I have a enum called DareStatus which is a list of statuses and their corresponding integer ID's. To minimize bandwidth traffic I want to send the int values of the enums, not the full text as it is currently doing. (I have control over the client so I can map it on the clientside). The strange thing is that in my RTFM-ing everyone seems to have the opposite issue!

http://www.ftter.com/desktopmodules/framework/api/dare/getalldares

```
public enum DareStatus : int
{
    All = 0,
    Accepted = 2,
    Pending = 1,
    Declined = 3,
    Cancelled = 4,
    Failed = 5,
    Won = 6
}


    public IEnumerable<DareInfo> GetDares()
    {
        IEnumerable<DareInfo> dareInfos;
        using (IDataContext ctx = DataContext.Instance())
        {
            var rep = ctx.GetRepository<DareInfo>();
            dareInfos = rep.Get();

        }
        return dareInfos;
    }
```

Comment: How are you getting the enum values into a list? When you build the list, can't you just cast the enum option to an int? Posting some code would really be helpful.

Comment: Can you post the current output and the expected output, and define what DareStatus actually is

Comment: Apologies, code updated

Comment: Which format are you using? Json? i am unable to repro your issue. Could you share how DareInfo looks like?